# node edit tabs in a block

Tags: 7, theming, routes

Is it possible to move node edit tabs links in some block. I want to hide them from the orignal position and want to create a floating block which may contains all those links which are available in tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this?...

http://vimeo.com/79462942

I did this with some jQuery and CSS.

jQuery to create and place "button" - in my case, this is a font-awesome icon. This may seem strange, but we're placing the button inside the div.tabs tag, and then placing div.tabs tag inside the h1 tag...

```
// edit node buttons
(function($){
    // wait til everything loads before firing
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //insert edit icon into div.tabs
        $('div.tabs').prepend($("<i class=\"icon-edit\"></i>"));    
        //insert div.tabs into page title
        $('h1').prepend($('div.tabs'));
    }); 
})(jQuery);
```

Now, if this is all we did, it would look crazy! We need CSS to do the magic part...

```
/*first we hide div.tabs, but we also define properties for when we expose it later*/       
    div.tabs ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    padding:10px;
    margin-top:-10px;
    background:rgb(0,0,0);
    border: 0px none;
    width:260px;
    border-radius: 4px 0 4px 4px;
    z-index:100;
    }

/*this exposes the tabs when we hover over the icon!*/  
    a:hover.icon-edit,
    div.tabs:hover ul,
    div.tabs:active ul {
    display:block;
    }

/*position button - I want it to the left of the h1*/
    div.tabs {
    float:left;
    width:1em;
    }
```

Your selectors and styles may differ, but the essential thing is to have a trigger/button class (or id) that is inside the div you want to hide/show.

Comment: Thank you very much though I was thinking to put those link in some sort of block and than manipulate that block. But this is even better. Thanks again.